# Mysql LOAD_FILE() returns NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, upload, blob, homebrew

I want to insert a blob in MYSQL with LOAD_FILE(). It always returns NULL even if I select the specific picture with `select hex(LOAD_FILE('kachel.png'));`. I've already tried to flush privileges and do `grant file ON *.*  to root@localhost;` but there is no change. I've also set my secure_file_priv to the folder I want (I've installed mysql with brew) so if I run `SELECT @@secure_file_priv;` it returns `/usr/local/var/mysql/mysql-files/`. Any recommendations?

Comment: The file must posess in `@@secure_file_priv` directory, and its pathname must be specified completely: `select hex(LOAD_FILE('/usr/local/var/mysql/mysql-files/kachel.png'));`

Comment: @Akina what do you mean by "it must possess a @@secure_file_priv directory?

Comment: And how can I load a file from another directory?

Comment: Use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`. But in this case both client and server must have `@@local_infile` enabled - see Reference Manual.

Comment: I want to add the image to a column of an existing table,. To `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` is no good option for me. But the specification of the pathname has worked - thank you!